# Why do I get this error `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2))`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using devise and reCaptcha.
Right after I signed up, `Something went wrong` error occured.
So I took a look at log. it says this.

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1366ms

Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

Everything was working perfectly in development mode, then why I'm getting this in production mode?

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
4. def create
5.     if verify_recaptcha
6.         super
7.         flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)
8.         else
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'd say there is problem with my action mailer setting.  But it was working fine in development mode. Why?

Comment: Maybe your mail server doesn't accept connections?

Comment: How would *I* know? Some settings and/or environment are different

Comment: @bronislav It was working fine in development mode:( really weird.

Comment: @HUSTEN Do you use the same mail server and mailer setting in both development and production?

Comment: @bronislav I didn't even mention any in both development.rb and production.rb :(

Comment: Everything was working fine in development mode

Comment: @bronislav I added more info to my question. could you please check and see?

Answer (score 1):

So, you din't setup action mailer both in development and production. I don't know why all works in development. May be you have a local mailserver? [By default](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) actionmailer try to use smtp server at `localhost:25`.

As one option, try to set `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test` in your `production.rb` and see if problem will gone. This setting will tell action mailer not to send emails but write email header and content to the log file.

Comment: I pasted `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test` to production.rb and signed up, however the same result:( By the way I'm using Rails3.2.11, Apache2, Passenger, Sendmail, reCaptcha and Devise.

Comment: So, you use sendmail. Where is your sendmail settings? As, I mention above, action mailer use smtp delivery method and i didn't see that you override this default.

Comment: I seriously have no clue. It's really weird that sendmail was working fine in development mode:( How can I fix?

Comment: If I did this command "hostname | mail -s "TEST" name@xxxxxxxxx.com" it sends email fine. So sendmail is working fine but my rails app in production mode:(

Comment: What you mean saying that all work in development environment? You receive email from devise or just don't get this error?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a mailer error. It seems like a sunspot's error due to lack of connection. Try to start sunspot in production:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production
```